# Show title attribute when hovering then revert back to original text when not hovering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I hover on either of the 'new-text' divs, I want to replace the text in my first div with the title attribute of the div being hovered on, and then revert back to the original text when no longer being hovered on. I don't think this can be done with CSS.

The original text and the titles are dynamic variables which will change depending on the page you are on, so any solution needs to not have hard coded values in it.

```
<div class='changing-text'>Original text</div>

<div class='new-text' title='New text 1'>Div 1</div>

<div class='new-text' title='New text 2'>Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello here is my code simple fix

```js
$(".new-text").mouseenter(function() {
     var title = $(this).attr('title');
     var orignal = $('.changing-text').text();

     $(this).attr('data-orignal',orignal);
     $('.changing-text').text(title);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
     var orgnl =  $(this).attr('data-orignal');
     $('.changing-text').text(orgnl);
         
    });
```

```css
.container div {
    display: inline-flex;
}
 .new-text {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='changing-text'>Original text</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class='new-text' title='New text 1'>Div 1</div>
  <div class='new-text' title='New text 2'>Div 2</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This work fine but code goes code goes more and complex try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64439600/show-title-attribute-when-hovering-then-revert-back-to-original-text-when-not-ho/64439965#64439965

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

This saved the original text of the hoved element before we change the text and when you leave/hoverout then we insert the original text again.

```
var original ="";

$('.new-text').hover(
  function() {
    original = $(this).text();
    $(this).text($(this).attr("title"));
  }, function() {
    $(this).text(original);
  }
);
```

**Demo**

```js
var original ="";

$('.new-text').hover(
  function() {
    original = $('.changing-text').text();
    $('.changing-text').text($(this).attr("title"));
  }, function() {
    $('.changing-text').text(original);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='changing-text'>Original text</div>

<div class='new-text' title='New text 1'>Div 1</div>

<div class='new-text' title='New text 2'>Div 2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, however I want the text of the first div to be changed to the titles of the second/third (depending on which is being hovered on), not for the second's/third's texts to change.

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting you right than try this one.

Yes you think right it is not possible with only `css` you have to use `jQuery` for that.
Try this solution.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var changing_text = jQuery('.changing-text').text();
    
    jQuery('.new-text').hover(function(){ 
        var title_value = jQuery(this).attr("title");
        jQuery('.changing-text').text(title_value);
    }, function(){ 
       jQuery('.changing-text').text(changing_text);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='changing-text'>Original text</div>

<div class='new-text' title='New text 1'>Div 1</div>

<div class='new-text' title='New text 2'>Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it once yourself first before throwing a question up here, or show your attempt if you have done so

Using CSS [:hover selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

`.new-text:hover {}`

Using Native JS [mouseover event](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

`<div onmouseover="()=>{}"></div>`

Using jQuery [hover event](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp)

`$(".new-text").hover(()=>{})`